Redisio.lettuce.core.RedisConnectionException: Unable to connect to localhost/<unresolved>:6379
My spring-cloud project with nacos, run success on debug, but build to jar run on server have error:
Caused by: io.lettuce.core.RedisConnectionException: Unable to connect to localhost/<unresolved>:6379
    at io.lettuce.core.RedisConnectionException.create(RedisConnectionException.java:78)
    at io.lettuce.core.RedisConnectionException.create(RedisConnectionException.java:56)
    at io.lettuce.core.AbstractRedisClient.getConnection(AbstractRedisClient.java:330)
    at io.lettuce.core.RedisClient.connect(RedisClient.java:216)
    at org.springframework.data.redis.connection.lettuce.StandaloneConnectionProvider.lambda$getConnection$1(StandaloneConnectionProvider.java:115)
    at java.base/java.util.Optional.orElseGet(Optional.java:364)
    at org.springframework.data.redis.connection.lettuce.StandaloneConnectionProvider.getConnection(StandaloneConnectionProvider.java:115)
    at org.springframework.data.redis.connection.lettuce.LettuceConnectionFactory$ExceptionTranslatingConnectionProvider.getConnection(LettuceConnectionFactory.java:1595)

I have config with：
spring.redis.host=hostName         
spring.redis.port=6379  
spring.redis.password=password

Why still error?
sucess on debug error on jar server

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
